# Run SQL Job Agent via Macro Excel by Windows Authentication

Tags: excel, vba, ssis

I have macro to run manually SQL Job Agent by using userid and Password

```
Sub Run_Job()
Dim con As Object
   Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   con.Open = "Provider=sqloledb; Data Source=SERVERNAME; Initial Catalog=DATABASENAME; User Id=USERNAME; Password=PASSWORD;"

con.Execute "exec msdb.dbo.sp_start_job ‘AGENTJOBNAME’"
Workbooks("WORKBOOKNAME.xlsx").Close
End Sub
```

But when my SQL Server must using Windows Authentication to login ,

how to create macro by using windows auth to run it?

Answer (score 0):

Do small correction to your connection string

```
con.Open = "Provider=sqloledb; Data Source=SERVERNAME; Initial Catalog=DATABASENAME; Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

It switches to integrated authentication.